# Getting data from firebase and eventually calling a hook inside .once infinite loading problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

When I get data from firebase I call a hook in the response but it makes it infinite load it. So I'm uploading a file to firebase using the filePond plugin which is working (code not shown below). Once the file is uploaded I want to load it in the component again.

So before we upload a new file I'm checking if the file already exists in the Firebase DB if so I want to set it with a useState hook but it makes it infinite load the image.

```
const ImageUpload = ({ firebase }) => {
  const ImageUpload = ({ firebase }) => {
  const [files, setFiles] = useState([])
  const userId = useSelector(state => state.user.userId)

  firebase
    .imagesUser()
    .child(userId)
    .once('value', snapshot => {
      if (snapshot.val() !== null) {
        setFiles([
          {
            source: snapshot.val().downloadURL,
            options: {
              type: 'local'
            }
          }
        ])
      }
    })

  return (
    <div className="imageUpload">
      <FilePond
        files={files}
       />
     </div>
  )
}
```

I want to set the data I got from firebase with a hook inside the firebase instance but the hook keeps firing. (infinite loop)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, @Kyle . Can you post the component, not just the section of the code as to provide more context?

Comment: Sung M. Kim Thank you for the quick reply! I added some more info I hope it helps!

Comment: you can't call a hook as a callback. I couldn't figure out what you are trying to do though :-( what is useSelector supposed to do? maybe you would rather set some state and add a useEffect for that state and then do your thing?

Comment: @erich thank you for the respnse! The useslector is to get state from the redux store. So you suggest setting a variable inside the firebase function and watching for the variable to change ?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your dependency would be, but you will need to create a useEffect listening to some specific state that you have. Does FilePond have an onChange or something? When the user uploads a new file you might want to set some state and based on that state change, you call firebase. e.g. `useEffect(() => { /* firebase stuff */ }, [userUploadedFile])`. 

Comment: @erich menezes I used a effect hook like you suggested and got it to work! Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!